# When I turn on CSRF protection, it forbids all of my requests | Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, csrf, csrf-token

I was developing my Spring Boot app, with CSRF disabled in my Security Config: http.csrf().disable(). But then I read that it is necessary to keep my website safe, so I turned it back on:

```
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.HttpStatusEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                //.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/profile").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .headers().frameOptions().disable()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED));

        http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

Yet, now, when I send any request other than GET to my server, it just forbids any request, even those that don't require authentication or anything. And when I look at the cookies or headers of a response, I don't see any headers regarding CSRF, that can possibly have the CSRF token.

I've tried looking for this information on the internet, and asking Chat-GPT, but I could not find the solution.

Comment: Do you understand that you need to provide a token in each non-GET request? have you read https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/features/exploits/csrf.html#csrf-protection-stp

Comment: And https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/csrf.html#csrf-integration